# Make a batch file give itself admin privilages and self destruct

Tags: batch-file, virus

I am coding a virus using some BSOD code (I didn't make that part of it) and I want the file to, one started, give itself admin privilages, set the date and time to a certain point, and once the system date and time hit a certain point, self destruct. The problem I'm coming accross is that, the file is stuck on the process of keeping the BSOD on the screen, so it never gets to the self destruct code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I've tried looping it and putting the code to when the loop reaches a certain point, move on. Didn't work.

```
@echo off
set loopcount=1
:loop
(
echo ^<html^>^<head^>^<title^>Microsoft Windows^</title^> 
echo. 
echo ^<hta:application id="oBVC" 
echo applicationname="BSOD"  
echo version="1.0" 
echo maximizebutton="no" 
echo minimizebutton="no" 
echo sysmenu="no" 
echo Caption="no" 
echo windowstate="maximize"/^>
```

(This is the beggining of the code. It should loop once, then self destruct itself)

```
start "" /wait "bsod.hta"

del /f /q "bsod.hta" > nul  
set /a loopcount=loopcount-1
if %loopcount%==0 goto exitloop
goto loop

:exitloop

del "%~f0" & exit
```

(This is the part where it should have made itself self destruct after the loop happened)

I expected it to loop once, the self destruct, ending all processes. It just stayed on the process of holding up the BSOD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is malicious in nature.

Comment: The first code fragment is incomplete (there is a `(` but no `)`). What do you want to do with this after all?

Answer (score 0):

> I expected it to loop once, the self destruct, ending all processes.
>   It just stayed on the process of holding up the BSOD

Your start /wait command will most certainly wait until the hta file has been closed prior to continuing execution of the rest of the batch file. If you wish to have the hta display and continue execution, just remove the /wait

```
start "bsod.hta"
```